# How to do I add an extra "next" button using jQuery Cycle?

Tags: jquery-cycle

I created a jquery cycle slideshow with next/prev buttons, but in addition to that, I want the slideshow to advance when the image is clicked. I don't know javascript well enough yet to code it myself. Is this possible? Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#illustration .slides').cycle({
speed:  1,
timeout: 0,
prev: '#illustration .prev',
next: '#illustration .next',
pager: '#illustration-thumbs',
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
  return '#illustration-thumbs li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
}
});

$('#illustration img').cycle('next');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use your container for the images as a next button if you add swap your next code you have at the moment to this

```
next: '#illustration .next, #container_div_name',
```

Hopefully that should achieve what you are after